# Spark SFTP NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load

Tags: apache-spark, sftp

When I execute the Spark code below using the SFTP library I get:

> 18/03/01 12:16:07 INFO sftp.DefaultSource: Copying
>   /output/skytree_output_201801.csv to
>   /hadoop/user/fl/data/skytree_output_201801.csv 18/03/01 12:16:07
>   INFO client.SFTPClient: Copying files from
>   /output/skytree_output_201801.csv to
>   /hadoop/user/fl/data/skytree_output_201801.csv 18/03/01 12:16:07
>   **INFO client.SFTPClient: Copied files successfully... Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame;
>           at com.springml.spark.sftp.DatasetRelation.read(DatasetRelation.scala:44)**

I don't know what I am missing here. My build.sbt file looks like this:

> name := "SftpToHDFS"
>
> version := "0.1"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at
>   "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
>
> resolvers += "cloudera" at
>   "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
>
> libraryDependencies ++=
>   Seq(  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
>     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"  % "provided",
>     "com.springml" % "spark-sftp_2.10" % "1.0.2"
>
> )

I have searched for this error and have not yet found anything that resolves the problem. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
package main

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object SftpToHDFS {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder
            .master("local")
            .appName("SftpToHDFS")
            .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
            .enableHiveSupport
            .getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._
        val df = spark.read.
            format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
            option("host", "ftp.site.com").
            option("username", "fl").
            option("password", "****").
            option("fileType", "csv").
            option("delimiter", ",").
            option("inferSchema", "true").
            option("tempLocation", "/hadoop/user/fl/data").
            load("/output/skytree_output_201801.csv")

        df.show(10)
    } 
}
```

Comment: OK, I figured out the problem. I was using the wrong version of the sftp library. Changed it to spark-sftp_2.11 it now it works.

Comment: Hello! I faced a similar problem, changing the versions of the library did not solve the problem. Can you check my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392096/how-convert-dataframe-to-csv-file-and-put-it-to-remote-sftp-server) about this problem and say what's wrong?